# Notepad++ regex for find and replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want a regex for notepad++ which should replace the line below with a blank.

```
[
    "product": [
        "573431ha-c146-4114-aed9-12ade154e359",
        "06958d7d-5f00-4130-9436-2b099918fc47"
    ],
    "id": "0438c966-e9h1-4457-b8e6-e02h890dc366",
]
```

I've already tried `"id"="([\w]+|[\w])"`, but it only detects alphanumeric characters (like `"acdB233"`), but nothing including punctuation (such as `"fffdfd-7"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you're looking for (assuming you want to only replace the `"id"` parameter) is

```
"id":\s*("[\w\-]+")
```

It'll group on whatever the parameter's value is, and will match both "word" characters (alphanumerics) and hyphens, like in your example.

For the `"product"` parameter, it's a bit more complicated - something like

```
"product":\s*(\[\n?\s*[\w\n\s\-,"]+\n?\s*\])
```

The group in the second regex will match the square brackets around the values in `"product"`. If you want to replace the two individual values in `"product"`, go with something like this:

```
"product":\s*\[\n?\s*((?:["\w\-]+,?\n?\s*)+)\]
```

Or, perhaps more simply,

```
("(?:\w-)+\w+")
```

Which will match all the alphanumeric-with-dash elements of your JSON text.

You can read up on regexes (and how to build them yourself) [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

Comment: "product":\s*\[\n?(?:("[\w\-]+"),?\n?)+\] and "product":\s*(\[[\w\n\s\-,"]\]) not working

Comment: Fixed, my bad. Forgot some of the spacing/newlines.

Comment: Added a link to my answer.

Comment: For filter out the "," comma for both id and products what i have to add in regular expression